# save Combobox item 3,4 delphi

Tags: delphi, combobox

I have a Combobox with 3 item by Default and I want to save items like this:

```
Item1 //don't save
Item2 //Don't save
Items3 //save
//save all futur items added
```

Why my code it's don't work?

```
if Combobox1.ItemIndex > 2 then // i used 2 for test and it's no work
   Combobox1.Items.SaveToFile('util.conf');
end;
```

If I remove *if Combobox1.ItemIndex > 2 then* all items are saved...

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Probably because ItemIndex is not > 2. 'SaveToFile' will save all items regardless, your 'if' statement will only determine if the 'SaveToFile' statement will run or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy the items to a temporary list and then remove whichever you want to remove from that temporary list. Then save it. For example, this code will remove the first two element from the list.

```
TempList := TStringList.Create;
try
  TempList.Assign(ComboBox1.Items);
  if TempList.Count>0 then
    TempList.Delete(0);
  if TempList.Count>0 then
    TempList.Delete(0);
  TempList.SaveToFile('util.conf');
finally
  TempList.Free;
end;
```

I'm not sure if I fully understand which elements of the list need to be removed. No matter, the basic idea of copying to a different list and saving that, is almost certainly what you need. You will surely be able to work out which elements need to be deleted.

Comment: Thank you for reply, So it's no work because all items are saved with your example.. my code for example http://pastebin.com/5g26Yp2V i used 2tbutton,1Tedit,1combobox and in object inspector i have added 3 items. you know why it's no work?

Comment: The code works fine. It does not save all the items. I made an even simpler example. I think you need to be sure that you fully understand the code. Stack Overflow can help you, but you need to understand the answers rather than blindly pasting them and asking for help when they don't do precisely what you want. Try to concentrate on understanding why code does what it does.

Comment: Yes David,I understand your example.i misread the answer so sorry!